Bridging tap interfaces with netplan
I would need to bridge two tap interfaces for OpenVPN servers and no physical interface. I have configured netplan as below. OpenVPN tap interface is in state "UNKNOWN" even it is up, with active client and working. I think this is the reason why my bridge is in state "DOWN". Is there some way to force state "UP" without adding some "UP" interface to it?
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
    tap0:
      optional: true
    tap1:
      optional: true
    tap2:
      optional: true
    tap3:
      optional: true

  bridges:
    br0:
      addresses: [ 192.168.25.1/24 ]
      interfaces: [ tap0, tap1, tap2, tap3 ]

Regards,
Jiri
